# How to determine the number of combinations

Tags: permutations, combinations

If there is n length sequence of 0's and 1's . Out of all possible sequences, how do do you determine the the number of sequences that does not contain the pattern 1011 in them ?

Comment: You could try doing it for $n=1,2,\dots,6$, say, and then consulting the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A049864 counts binary sequences of length $n-2$ with no subsequence $0110$; it agrees with your sequence at least as far as length $7$, where both give $97$. Maybe they are the same. The page gives a simple recurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n$ be the number of binary sequence of length $n$ that do not contain the string $1011$; call such sequences *good*. Let $b_n$ be the number of good sequences that end in $101$, $c_n$ the number that end in $10$, and $d_n$ the number that end in $1$.

To make a good sequence of length $n+1$, you can append either $0$ or $1$ to any good sequence of length $n$ **except** one that ends in $101$, so $a_{n+1}=2a_n-b_n$. To make a good sequence of length $n+1$ that ends in $101$, you must append a $1$ to a good sequence of length $n$ that ends in $10$, so $b_{n+1}=c_n$. To make a good sequence of length $n+1$ that ends in $10$, you must append a $0$ to a good sequence of length $n$ that ends in $1$, so $c_{n+1}=d_n$. And to make a good sequence of length $n+1$ that ends in $1$, you must append a $1$ to a good sequence of length $n$ that does **not** end in $101$, so $d_{n+1}=a_n-b_n$. Thus,

$$a_{n+1}=2a_n-b_n\;,$$

and

$$b_{n+1}=c_n=d_{n-1}=a_{n-2}-b_{n-2}\;,$$

or, after shifting the indices,

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=2a_{n-1}-b_{n-1}\tag{1}\\
b_n&=a_{n-3}-b_{n-3}\;.\tag{2}
\end{align*}$$

From $(1)$ we get $a_{n-3}=2a_{n-4}-b_{n-4}$ and hence $a_{n-4}-b_{n-4}=a_{n-3}-a_{n-4}$, and from $(2)$ we have $b_{n-1}=a_{n-4}-b_{n-4}$; substituting into $(1)$ yields the recurrence

$$a_n=2a_{n-1}-(a_{n-4}-b_{n-4})=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}\;,$$

with initial values $a_k=2^k$ for $k=0,1,2,3$. This confirms that the sequence is [OEIS A049864](http://oeis.org/A049864), as suggested by Gerry Myerson in the comments, but shifted two places to the left, with without the first two terms of that sequence. No nice closed form is given.

Comment: Of course, having the recursion, a closed form can be obtained. But it will involve the roots of the polynomial $x^4-2x^3+x-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Inclusion exclusion. Mouseover the grey area for the [horrible] series.

> There are $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0} (-1)^kc_k$ length $n$ strings without $1011$. $c_0=2^n$ sequences have length $n$. In any sequence with $1011$ there are $2^{n-4}$ possibilities for the remaining bits, and $n-3$ places where the $1011$ can start, so $c_1=2^{n-4}(n-3)$ or $0$ if $n<4$. Sequences with two $1011$s have been over-counted, and the two $1011$s may overlap; there are $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n-7}n-5-k= (n-7)(n-5)-\frac{1}2(n-7)(n-6)$ ways to place them and $2^{n-8}$ ways to place the remaining bits. Subsequent $c_k$ are found similarly.